# How to call a view function to templates in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I am developing web application using python-django framework. What I want to achieve, is to display a dropdown list in my index.html template. Dropdown list must be fill in with data from the database.

This is my data in database.

```
 id(PK)  cdistid   cdistname 

 1        01       District 1
 2        02       District 2
 .
 .
 .
 13       13       District 13
```

I want to display all the **cdistname** in my dropdown forms.

This is my models.py

```
class District(models.Model) :
  cdistid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  cdistname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  def __unicode__(self):
     return self.cdistname
```

This is my forms.py where my dropdown form are declared.

```
from django import forms
from butuan_parcel.models import District
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

class ShowDist(forms.Form) :
   subject = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = District.objects.all())
```

This is my views.py, calling my forms class

```
from butuan_parcel.forms import ShowDist

def showdist(request):
drpdown = ShowDist()
return HttpResponseRedirect(request, "index.html", {'dropdown': drpdown})
```

How can I call this into my index.html to display my dropdown form.?? Or someone can correct my codes above,. I think there is something missing.., any help is very much appreciated.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This code will resolve your issue
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from butuan_parcel.models import District
class ShowDist(forms.Form) :
   subject = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = District.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
from butuan_parcel.forms import ShowDist
def showdist(request):
    form = ShowDist()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'form' : form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action='.' method='GET'>
      {{form.subject}}
      <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
  </body
</html>
```